# Custom Wordpress plugin crashes frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom plugin that was previously coded into functions.php and worked fine.  I extracted the code and I am creating a stand-alone plugin with it.  When I do, the website's backend is fine and the plugin does what it is supposed to do, however the frontend shows a 500 error.

```
<?php
function add_bulk_coupons() {
$prod = new MM_Product();
$selectedProds = array();

$id = 0; 

if(isset($p->id))
{
    $id = $p->id;
}

$coupon = new MM_Coupon($id);
$prods = $coupon->getProducts();

if(!$coupon->isValid())
{
    $coupon->setStartDate(Date("m/d/Y"));
}

$editable = "";

if(MM_Coupon::isBeingUsed($coupon->getId()))
{
    $editable = "disabled='disabled'";
}

$products = MM_HtmlUtils::createCheckboxGroup(MM_Product::getAll(),         "mm_products", $prods);

/*
//testing coupon restr
$x = 30;
while($x <= 1029):

    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO mm_coupon_restrictions (coupon_id, product_id)     VALUES ('".$x."','1')";
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $sql ) );

    $x++;
endwhile;
*/
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)):
    global $wpdb;
    $coupon_variables = '';
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value):
        if($key == 'number_of_coupons' || $key == 'mm_products' || $key ==     'coupon_name' || $key == 'coupon_code') continue;
        if($value == '') $value = NULL;
        if($key == 'end_date' || $key == 'start_date'):
            $value = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($value));
        endif;
        if($coupon_variables==''):
            $coupon_variables .= "'".$value."'";
        else:
            $coupon_variables .= ','."'".$value."'";
        endif;
    endforeach;
    $x = 1;
    while($x <= $_POST['number_of_coupons']):
        $coupon_name = $_POST['coupon_name'].$x;
        $rand = rand(10000000, 90000000);
        $coupon_code = $_POST['coupon_code'].$rand;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO mm_coupons (coupon_name, coupon_code,     coupon_type, coupon_value, coupon_value_currency, description, quantity, start_date, end_date, recurring_billing_setting, is_gift, gift_user_id, gift_order_item_id, date_modified, date_added) VALUES ('".$coupon_name."','".$coupon_code."',".$coupon_variables.")";
        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( $sql ) );
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM mm_coupons ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $theid = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
        //print_r( $theid );
        $x++;
    endwhile;
    echo '<div class="success" style="color: #000;background-color: #ebf8a4;border-color: #a2d246;margin: 1em 0 1em;border: 1px solid;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 10px 50%;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff inset;-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff inset;box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff inset;">Successfully Created '.$_POST['number_of_coupons'].' Coupons. <a href="https://www.hurlbutvisuals.com/blog/wp-admin/admin.php?page=product_settings&module=coupons">View Them Now</a></div>';
endif;
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="mm-coupons-container">
        <br />

        <h3>Create your coupons</h3>
        <table cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td width="140">Name Prefix*</td>
                <td><input type='hidden' id='id' value='<?php echo $coupon->getId(); ?>' />
                    <input id="mm_coupon_name" name="coupon_name" type="text" value='<?php echo $coupon->getCouponName(); ?>' style='width:300px;' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="140">Coupon Code Prefix*</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="mm_coupon_code" name="coupon_code" <?php echo $editable; ?>  type="text" value='<?php echo strtoupper($coupon->getCouponCode()); ?>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="140">Discount*</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="mm_coupon_type" name="coupon_type" <?php echo $editable; ?> onchange="mmjs.typeChangeHandler();">
                        <option value='<?php echo MM_Coupon::$TYPE_PERCENTAGE; ?>' <?php echo (($coupon->getCouponType() == MM_Coupon::$TYPE_PERCENTAGE)?"selected":""); ?>>% Off</option>  
                        <option value='<?php echo MM_Coupon::$TYPE_DOLLAR; ?>' <?php echo (($coupon->getCouponType() == MM_Coupon::$TYPE_DOLLAR)?"selected":""); ?>>$ Off</option>  
                        <option value='<?php echo MM_Coupon::$TYPE_FREE; ?>' <?php echo (($coupon->getCouponType() == MM_Coupon::$TYPE_FREE)?"selected":""); ?>>Free</option>                   
                    </select>
                    <input id="mm_coupon_value" name="coupon_value" <?php echo $editable; ?> type="text" value='<?php echo $coupon->getCouponValue(); ?>' style="width:85px;" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="coupon_value_currency" value='' />
                    <input type="hidden" name="description" value='' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Number of coupons to create</td>
                <td>
                    <input id="mm_quantity" name="quantity" type="hidden" style='width: 80px;' value='1' />
                    <input id="mm_quantity" name="number_of_coupons" type="text" style='width: 80px;' value='<?php echo $coupon->getQuantity(); ?>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" width="140">Restrictions</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="140">Start Date</td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo MM_Utils::getCalendarIcon(); ?>
                                <input id="mm_start_date" name="start_date" type="text" value='<?php echo $coupon->getStartDate(); ?>' style="width:110px;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>End Date</td>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo MM_Utils::getCalendarIcon(); ?>
                                <input id="mm_end_date" name="end_date" type="text" value='<?php echo $coupon->getEndDate(); ?>' style="width:110px;" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <div style="width: 98%; margin-top: 8px;" class="mm-divider"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="140" style="vertical-align:top;">Subscription Options</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="mm_subscription_options_section">
                        <p style="margin:0px 0px 5px 0px;"><input id="mm_recurring_setting_first" <?php echo $editable; ?> name="recurring_billing_setting" type="radio" value='first' <?php echo (($coupon->getRecurringBillingSetting()=="first")?"checked":""); ?> /> Apply discount to the first charge only</p>
                        <p style="margin:10px 0px 0px 0px;"><input id="mm_recurring_setting_all" <?php echo $editable; ?> name="recurring_billing_setting" type="radio" value='all' <?php echo (($coupon->getRecurringBillingSetting()=="all")?"checked":""); ?> /> Apply discount to all charges</p>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="is_gift" value='0' />
                    <input type="hidden" name="gift_user_id" value='0' />
                    <input type="hidden" name="gift_order_item_id" value='0'     />

                    <input type="hidden" name="date_modified" value='<?php     echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>' />
                    <input type="hidden" name="date_added" value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); ?>' />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <div style="width: 98%; margin-top: 8px;" class="mm-divider"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <tr valign='top'>
                    <td valign='top'>Valid Products</td>
                    <td valign='top'>
                        <div style="overflow: auto; height: 165px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
                        <?php echo $products; ?>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("#mm_start_date").datepicker();
                jQuery("#mm_end_date").datepicker();
            });
        </script>

        <div class="mm-dialog-footer-container">
        <div class="mm-dialog-button-container">
            <button class="mm-ui-button blue">Save Coupon</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Show us the error log, it hard to help you without see it.

Comment: is that the actual, entire code of your plug, or just the function that you think is the problem?

Comment: That is the function part.  I removed the "header" where it declares it as a plugin

Comment: new MM_Coupon() if this class is defined in the theme or in a plugin that gets loaded after yours, it will fail. use the init hook or something to work with classes (you should do this anyway unless you really need to run code before themes are loaded) you should also turn on errors, a 500 error is not very specific !

Comment: Well if I'm guessing here, Torsten, I think your issue may be in having so much exposed HTML in your PHP. 

Personally, whether its in a plugin or in my functions.php file, I NEVER close a PHP tag to expose raw HTML - thats just asking for trouble in my book.

Use an "echo" instead.

Comment: Edd, the thing is that the code as pasted above runs as part of 'functions.php; but when I separate it into its own, it will run as expected in the backend, but the site's frontend crashes.